# How to check if folder or file is locked, opened, or in-use

Tags: c#, uwp

I have searched high and low for a good solution to checking if a folder or file is locked for UWP app.  Most stuff I have found is very dated using some kind of stream. After a long search, I found a low rated post that indicates Windows will not allow a folder or file to be renamed if content is in use.

I realize best way to handle this situation is through proper exception use but I have app that archives files but can not remove original folder at end since a file is opened.  This creates all kinds of unexpected results that can not be handled including original user data loss.

So I post these quick solutions I have discovered that works in hope it may help someone else from an endless search.

Comment: "So I post these quick solutions I have discovered that works in hope it may help someone else from an endless search." -> Are you asking and answering your own question then? If you are, that's great, but I just wanted to clarify since there's no answer as of yet.

Comment: Which folders are to be archived? I ask this since UWP apps have restricted access to the file system, it cannot access files other than the those in libraries (which requires declared explicitly in appx manifest). If you are to archive the files in the app's appdata folder, then only the app itself has access to the folder so in general you don't need to worry about files being opened by another process.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
    /// Check if StorageFile is locked. Return true if locked, false otherwise.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="StorageFileToCheck">StorageFile to check if locked.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<Boolean> StorageFileLocked(StorageFile StorageFileToCheck)
    {
        // If StorageFileToCheck can't be deleted, then rename attempt will cause System.UnauthorizedAccessException indicating StorageFileToCheck is locked.
        string stringFilenameTemp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + StorageFileToCheck.FileType;
        string stringFilenameOrig = StorageFileToCheck.Name;
        Debug.WriteLine($"StorageFileLocked(): stringFoldernameTemp={stringFilenameTemp}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"StorageFileLocked(): stringFoldernameOrig={stringFilenameOrig}");
        try
        {
            // Try to rename file. If file is locked, then System.UnauthorizedAccessException will occur.
            await StorageFileToCheck.RenameAsync(stringFilenameTemp);
            await StorageFileToCheck.RenameAsync(stringFilenameOrig);     // Restore original name if no excpetion.
            Debug.WriteLine($"StorageFileLocked(): Returned false since no exception.");
            return false;   // Return false since no exception. File is not locked.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"StorageFileLocked(): Returned true since exception occurred. Type={ex.GetType()}");
            return true;    // Return true since exception. File is locked.
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if StorageFolder is locked. Return true if locked, false otherwise.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="StorageFolderToCheck">StorageFolder to check if locked.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<Boolean> StorageFolderLocked(StorageFolder StorageFolderToCheck)
    {
        // If StorageFolderToCheck can't be deleted, then rename attempt will cause System.UnauthorizedAccessException indicating StorageFolderToCheck is locked.
        string stringFoldernameTemp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        string stringFoldernameOrig = StorageFolderToCheck.Name;
        Debug.WriteLine($"StorageFolderLocked(): stringFoldernameTemp={stringFoldernameTemp}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"StorageFolderLocked(): stringFoldernameOrig={stringFoldernameOrig}");
        try
        {
            // Try to rename folder. If folder is locked, then System.UnauthorizedAccessException will occur.
            await StorageFolderToCheck.RenameAsync(stringFoldernameTemp);
            await StorageFolderToCheck.RenameAsync(stringFoldernameOrig);     // Restore original name if no excpetion.
            Debug.WriteLine($"StorageFolderLocked(): Returned false since no exception.");
            return false;   // Return false since no exception. Folder is not locked.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"StorageFolderLocked(): Returned true since exception occurred. Type={ex.GetType()}");
            return true;    // Return true since exception. Folder is locked.
        }
    }
```